# onLoginFinished callback is not fired in Login with Facebook

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm building a simple React Native app which implements "Login with Facebook" using [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk)
I can login and logout as the button changes from *Log in* to *Log out* when logging with credentials, but the `onLoginFinished` callback never gets fired, though `onLogoutFinished` works properly.

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View,Alert,Button,Text } from 'react-native';
import { LoginButton, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userInfo: null
    }
  }

  onFacebookLoginFinished = (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      Alert.alert("login has error: " + result.error);
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
      Alert.alert("login is cancelled.");
    } else {
      AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
        (data) => {
          Alert.alert(data.accessToken.toString())
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
        }
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <LoginButton
          onLoginFinished={this.onFacebookLoginFinished}
          onLogoutFinished={() => Alert.alert("logout.")}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try this.

```
onLoginFinished={(error, result) => this.onFacebookLoginFinished(error, result)}
```

Change the function into this.

```
onFacebookLoginFinished (error, result){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `onLoginFinished` method from:

```
onLoginFinished={this.onFacebookLoginFinished}
```

To:

```
onLoginFinished={(error, result) => this.onFacebookLoginFinished(error, result)}
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code?

Try doing it yourself in a function.

```js
onLoginFinished={(error, data) => {
               if (error) {
      Alert.alert("login has error: " + result.error);
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
      Alert.alert("login is cancelled.");
    } else {
      AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
        (data) => {
          Alert.alert(data.accessToken.toString())
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
        }
      )
    }
          }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing the component instance (`this`), so you'll need to bind to your onLoginFinished function, perefarbly in your constructor, i.e.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    userInfo: null
  }

  this.onFacebookLoginFinished = this.onFacebookLoginFinished.bind(this);
}
```

See further explanation and more options here: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#bind-in-constructor-es2015

Comment: But arrow functions are not needed to bind, are they?

Comment: but why? they are arrow fuctions in the first place

Comment: @Pavindu Good point. I don't know the inner workings of React well enough, but at the moment, your approach is described 'experimental and not standardized' in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#class-properties-stage-3-proposal

Comment: @eronisko  Thanks for pointing that out. I am also not very well aware of React. I didn't know about that.